# Find the maximum and minimum value of $2x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ subject to $x + y + z = 10$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am working on inequality problems for mathematical olympiads. I have come across this problem:

> Find the maximum and minimum value of $2x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ subject to $x + y + z = 10$, with $x,y,z \ge 0 $

I found the minimum using Cauchy-Schwarz: $$100 = \left(\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \left(\sqrt 2 x\right) + y + z\right)^2 \le \left(\left(1/\sqrt 2\right)^2 + 1^2 + 1^2\right) \left(\left(\sqrt 2 x\right)^2 + y^2 + z^2\right)=2.5\left(2x^2 + y^2 + z^2\right)$$
so $2x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ge 40$ with equality if $x=2$ and $y=z=4$.

I am not sure how to find the maximum though. Could I have a hint? Ideally I would like to do it without using calculus, though if it is easy to do with calculus feel free to share the method.

Comment: @DonThousand good point. I forgot to add the condition that x,y,z are non-negative.

Comment: It seems obvious that the maximum in this case is 200 but I'm not sure how to prove it algebraically

Comment: $2x^2 + y^2 + z^ 2 \leq 2 (x+y+z)^2 = 200$.

Answer (score 4):

Some comments:

Both Tavish and Calvin Lin's solutions are good and are not just lucky. Let's break it down:

**Lemma:** If $a\ge 0, b\ge 0$ and $a+b$ is fixed, then $a^2+b^2$ obtains its maximum when either $a=0$ or $b=0$.

This can be proved either via property of parabola, or just algebraically. But it's easy to write it simply as $a^2+b^2 \le (a+b)^2$, and I believe nobody is against this.

Now if we fix $y+z$ we have $$2x^2 + (y^2 + z^2) \le 2x^2+ (y+z)^2 = 2x^2+ (10-x)^2 \tag 1$$

Next we apply the lemma on $x$ and $10-x$:
$$x^2+\left( x^2+(10-x)^2 \right)\le x^2 + (x+10-x)^2 = x^2 + 100 \tag 2$$
$$\le 100+100.\blacksquare$$

You can think of Calvin Lin's way as combining these two steps (or a generalized version of the lemma with more than two variables):
$$2x^2+y^2+z^2 = x^2 + (x^2+y^2+z^2) \le x^2 + (x+y+z)^2 = x^2 + 10^2 \le 200$$

Tavish's way is to apply the parabola property twice.

---

It's best understood from the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\sqrt2x$, $y=v$, $z=w$. Then, it is equivalent to find the maximum $k^2=u^2+v^2+w^2$ subject to
$$\frac u{10\sqrt2} + \frac v{10} + \frac w{10} =1\tag1$$

Observe that $k$ is the distance from the origin to the plane (1) with the axis-intercepts $10\sqrt2,10,10$. In the first quadrant, (1) is a tetrahedron with its furthest corner at the $x$-intercept $10\sqrt2$. Thus, the maximum is $k^2_{max}=(10\sqrt2)^2 =200$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the value of $z$ in the expression: $$2x^2 +y^2 +(x+y-10)^2 $$ As increasing $x$ and $y$ increases the value of this expression, the maximum occurs when $x+y$ is maximum, i.e. $x+y=10$: $$2x^2 +(10-x)^2 = 3x^2 -20x +100$$

This is a parabola which attains its maximum value on $[0,10]$ at $x=10$, which is $200$.

Comment: Not the best way to approach the problem I think.

Comment: @Forester Why not?

Comment: A much simpler approach is mentioned by Calvin Lin in the comments. Also, this is not a rigorous proof.

Comment: I disagree with you @Forester, actually it is the best and most rigorous method. Method presented by Calvin Lin is lucky guess.

Comment: @Forester I do think that Calvin’s way is simpler and quicker, but that doesn’t mean this is invalid. What do you mean by ‘rigorous’?

Comment: @Tavish I never said it was invalid tho. I said it is not rigorous because you did not prove everything algebraically.

Comment: @Aqua Are you being sarcastic? It is not very easy to understand the tone in the chatbox.

Comment: Ceartanly not, I meant what I wrote.

Comment: Just seeing this. It is not rigorous because the statement "increasing x and y increases the value of this expression" needs to be substantiated. Part of it which is $(x+y-10)^2$ does not necessarily increase with increasing $x, y$.

Comment: @Forester Sure, I didn’t prove everything in that sense. Take my answer as an idea rather than a proof.

Comment: @Aqua $(x+y-10)^2$ does not necessarily increase with an increase in $x$ and $y$. Also, the solution even if rigorous definitely not the most rigorous proof. Coming to the second part, at first sight, it may look like Calvin Lin's method is a lucky guess but We already know that the answer is 200 intuitively so we need to prove it somehow that the given expression <= 200. Therefore we can think of  $2(x+y+z))^2$. English is not my first language.

Comment: @Tavish  Take x=0,y=0 and x=1,y=1 for example or x=1,y=1 and x=2,y=2

Comment: $(x+y-10)^2 = 100$ for $x = y = 0$. That is the max value of this part of the overall expression with the given constraint of $x + y \leq 10$.

Comment: The set is a face of a tetrahedron. Both maximum and minimum are obtained in a corner vertex, on an edge or on the  face. The edges are given by $x+y+z=10$ and one of $x=0,y=0, z=0,$ the vertices by $x+y+z=10$ and two of the "zero" constraints.

Comment: @Forester And what if we didn’t already know the answer? Would saying what Calvin said be sufficient to prove that $200$ is indeed the maximum? No!

Comment: @Math Lover True, so I guess I cannot say te value of the expression increases necessarily with $x,y$. The tetrahedron argument above looks good.

Comment: @MathLover $x=10 , y=0, z=0$ is the answer and makes sense because you would want to maximise x since its coefficient is 2. However if you want to derive this solution through the equation $2x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 2((x+y+z)^2)$ It is very clear that equality holds when $y=z=0.(2x^2=2x^2)$ .You could also open the expression and prove it.

Comment: @Aqua I agree with you on this. If we didn't know the answer it would be difficult to directly think of that inequality but once we have written that inequality isn't it simple to see that inequality hold if and only if y = z =0.

Comment: @Forester yes the coefficient of $2$ is obvious and the first thing I noticed. So I agree with that argument. The point that I am making and I think even Aqua and Tavish are making is that it is very contextual. In general case, it would still need to be proven that we can attain max of $200$.

Comment: @Forester Yes, *if* we knew the answer.

Comment: @Tavish I think everything so far is as good as the argument that it is all symmetric other than the coefficient of $2$ with $x^2$. So give everything to $x$ and that has to maximize the expression!

Comment: @MathLover And that is a good argument. One could also look at it geometrically by picturing the spheroid given by $2x^2+y^2+z^2$, and increasing its size to just below the point when it has no intersection with the plane $x+y+z=10$ in the first octant.

Answer (score 1):

For a calculus-based method that delivers both solutions, you want a Lagrange multiplier. Let: \begin{align*}f\left(x,y,z\right) &= 2x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \\ g\left(x,y,z\right) &= x + y + z - 10\end{align*} The condition for an extremum is $$\vec{\nabla} f\left(x,y,z\right) = \lambda \vec{\nabla} g\left(x,y,z\right)$$ Calculating this out, we have a system with four equations and four unknowns: \begin{align*}4x &= \lambda \\ 2y &= \lambda \\ 2z &= \lambda \\ 0 &= x+y+z-10\end{align*}

Solving for $\lambda$ first is easiest: $$0 = \frac{\lambda}{4} + \frac{\lambda}{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} - 10 \hspace{2.00cm} \rightarrow \hspace{2.00cm} \lambda = 8$$ With $\lambda=8$ figured out, we know one extreme point to be: $$x = 2  \hspace{2.54cm} y = 4 \hspace{2.54cm} z = 4$$

---

So what about the maximum? The best hint, which undoubtedly drives the other solutions to this, is the factor of $2$ in front of $x^2$, meaning this term grows faster than its counterparts. It only makes sense to try $y=z=0$, so that $x=10$ is evident from inspection. This makes the whole $\lambda$-apparatus somewhat useless, but at least the form is there in case the problem was trickier than it looked.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{x}{10}, \frac{y}{10}, \frac{z}{10}\in[0; 1]$, we have that $\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)^2\leqslant\frac{x}{10}, \left(\frac{y}{10}\right)^2\leqslant\frac{y}{10}, \left(\frac{z}{10}\right)^2\leqslant\frac{z}{10}$. Thus \begin{align*}2x^2+y^2+z^2&=100\cdot \left(2\cdot\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{10}\right)^2+\left(\frac{z}{10}\right)^2\right)\\&\leqslant 100\cdot \left(2\cdot \frac{x}{10}+\frac{y}{10} +\frac{z}{10}\right)\\&=100\cdot \left(\frac{x}{10}+1\right)\\&\leqslant 100\cdot (1+1)=200\end{align*} With equality if and only if $x=10, y=0, z=0.$